# Can we run an FME from a powershell?

Tags: powershell, fme

I want to run an `FME.fmw` file from a `PowerShell.ps1` one. 
I know that I can do that from a batch with the command `fme C:\Path\of\fmw`
but I do not find a way to do it with `PowerShell`. 
Start-Process will only open `FME` and not launch it

```
$repertory_source = Read-Host "Path of file ? (X:\X\X.fmw)"
start-process -FilePath $repertory_source
```

I want to run the `FME.fmw` with no need to open the `FME workbench`.

Comment: Run the fme executable and supply the fmw file as an argument

Answer (score 0):

There is a direct way of calling FMW file and passing the arguments accordingly. See below the complete details.

FME can be run from the command line in Windows: Opening the Command Prompt window and typing FME gives the full list of options displayed below.

The command FME .fmw will run a particular workspace. Therefore, if FME workspaces can be called from the command line, a series of workspaces (or the same workspace with differing datasets) can be called from a DOS batch (.bat) file.

**Usage**

```
fme <controlFile> [<keyword> <value>]* [--<macroName> <value>]*
fme <scriptfile> [<scriptArgument>*]
fme <licenseFile>.fmelic
fme <command> <arguments>
where:
<controlFile> is one of <mappingFile>.fme or <workspace>.fmw
<scriptFile> is one of <tclScript>.tcl or <pythonScript>.py
<command> is one of:
```

Command Name Arguments

---

```
GENERATE <sourceType> <destType> <sourceDataset> <controlFile> [<keyword> <value>]*
PARAMETER_FILE <parameterFile>
COMMAND_FILE <commandFile>
REGISTER_SOCKET <hostName> <service> [serverConfigFile] [-<ServerParmName> <ServerParmValue>]*
CREATE_SOCKET <service> [serverConfigFile] [-<ServerParmName> <ServerParmValue>]*
GENTRANS [<keyword> <value>]* <parameterFile>
GENTRANS [<keyword> <value>]* <sourceType> <sourceDataset> <destType> <destDataset>
LIST_TRANSFORMERS [VERBOSE]
LIST_UNLICENSED_TRANSFORMERS
LIST_FACTORIES
LIST_FUNCTIONS
PROTECT <sourceFile> <destFile>
```

Reference Link [Batch Processing Method](https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/975/batch-processing-method-1-command-line-or-batch-fi.html)

Answer (score 0):

Letting users manually enter a possibly longer path is IMO error-prone and **NOT** user friendly.

I suggest to use the OpenFileDialog preequipped with file type(s) and starting directory.

```
## Q:\Test\2019\04\26\SO_55862942.ps1

Function Get-FileName($StartHere=[Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")){
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $OFD = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OFD.Title = "Please select fme file"
    $OFD.InitialDirectory = $StartHere
    $OFD.Filter = "fme workspace files (*.fmw)|*.fmw|fme parameter files (*.par)|*.par|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    $OFD.Multiselect = $False
    $OFD.ShowDialog() | Out-Null

    Get-Item $OFD.FileName
}

$FME = "C:\Program Files\fme\fme.exe"

$SelectedFile = Get-FileName  # -StartHere X\Path\  # optionally pass another Starting Directory

switch ($SelectedFile.Extension) {
    '.fmw' {& $FME "$($SelectedFile.FullName";Break}
    '.par' {& $FME PARAMETER_FILE "$($SelectedFile.FullName";Break}
    default {pause "[$_] Select a valid fme file, press enter to continue";break}
}
```